# Table-Scraper Not Returning Data Before Function Returns

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am currently working on a Discord bot, which uses node.js, to scrape info from Dododex.com, a database of creatures from the game ARK. I found a very useful library called [table-scraper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/table-scraper) which scrapes tables from web pages and returns the data as an object (or array of objects for multiple tables). In the background, table-scraper uses another library called [x-ray](https://www.npmjs.com/package/x-ray), along with the common web request-maker [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). Keep in mind that I don't know that much about node or how request works.

What I have working is asking the user for the name of a creature to get the data for. I then check that name against a list of creatures (that I have in a file/JSON object) to see if that name is valid.

Now, what I want to get working is to scrape the relevant data from the dododex page belonging to that creature using table-scraper. Table-scraper is definitely working with dododex, but when I call it to gather the data and put it into an object, it seems to start scraping, but then lets the function return with an empty object. If the program didn't crash right after the return (caused by the attempt to access an empty object), I know from testing that it would finish scraping, even though the function the scraping was called in has already finished.

Here's where the relevant code starts:

```js
const creature = getDinoFromName(args[0].toLowerCase(), arkdata); //Function explained below
if(creature.health.base == 404) //If the creature's name is invalid, getDinoFromName() will return a creature with health.base = 404
{
  console.log("unknown");
  unknownCreature(args, msg); //Tells the user that the creature is unknown
  return;
}
else
{
    //Outputs the data
}
```

And here's where the data gets gathered:

```js
function getDinoFromName(name, arkdata)
{
  for(let i = 0; i < arkdata.creatures.length; i++) //Loops through arkdata, a json object with the possible names of all the creatures
  {
    if(arkdata.creatures[i].possible_names.includes(name)) //If the name the user provided matches one of the possible names of a creature (creatures can have multiple possible names, i.e. rex, t-rex, tyrannosaurus rex)
    {
      var creature;
      console.log("found");
      tableScraper.get("http://www.dododex.com/taming/" + arkdata.creatures[i].possible_names[0]).then(function(tableData)
      {
        console.log("scraped");
        var stats = tableData[1]; //tableData is an array of 3 tables matching the 3 html tables found on the site, tableData[1] is the one with the creature's stats. It looks like this: http://ronsoros.github.io/?31db928bc662538a80bd25dd1207ac080e5ebca7
        creature = //Now the actual creature object, parsed from tableData[1]
        {
          "health":
          {
            "base": stats[0]["Base (Lvl 1)"], //
            "perwild": stats[0]["Increase Per Lvl (Wild)"],
            "pertamed": stats[0]["Increase Per Lvl (Tamed)"]
          }
          //There is more data to parse but I only included hp as an example
        }
      });
      return creature;
    }
  }
  //If the creature name is not found to be one of the possible names, returns this to signify the creature was not found
  return {"health":{"base":404}};
}
```

Running the code result in node crashing and the error

```
/app/server.js:320
  if(creature.health.base == 404)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'health' of undefined
at stats (/app/server.js:320:15)
at Client.client.on.msg (/app/server.js:105:7)
```

Something wonky is going on here, and I really can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I rolled back your edit, because it is inappropriate here to add SOLVED to the title or edit an answer into the question itself. If you've found a solution and would like to share it that's great, but you have to do it properly by writing an answer in the space provided below for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here, but thanks for letting me know.